# Object as function param in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

How I can set an object as function param with default values

Example:

```
function objasparam({obj1: {var1: 0, var2: "something"}, obj2: {...}}) {
   console.log(obj1.var1); //the expacted log is 0 but it is undefined
}
objasparam({
   obj1:{
     var2: "other"
   }
});
```

even if I do it this way there is an error

```
function objasparam(obj = {obj1: {var1: 0, var2: "something"}, obj2: {...}}) {
   console.log(obj.obj1.var1); //the expacted log is 0 but it is undefined
}
objasparam({
   obj1:{
     var2: "other"
   }
});
```

Comment: `function objasparam(obj = {obj1: {var1: 0, var2: "something"}})` will make `obj` equal to your object if nothing is specified as the first argument

Comment: but obj.obj1.var1 not equals 0 but undefined

Comment: you have no `obj` your in function. Look at my example there is your `obj` with the name `config` and `config.obj1.var1` is `0`

Comment: an other issue is that if config.obj1.var1 is changed var2 is lost but I need it later

Comment: thats no issue, thats how default objects works. They should be overwriteable. If you dont want to overwrite the default, than you dont have to call the function with new values. Delete the `objasparam({ obj1: { var1: 22, var2: "another string"}}); ` in my example and your default values are the original values

Comment: but why I can´t only override on of the default values and left the other as the default value in the function param like normal params in functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an default object. So you are not forced to have all parameters. 
If you have no arguments, the defaults exists.

```js
const objasparam = (config) => {
  let defaults = {
    obj1: {
      var1: 0,
      var2: "something"
    },
    obj2: {
      var1: 1
    }
  }

  config = {
    ...defaults,
    ...config
  }

  // to get your obj1.var1
  console.log(config.obj1.var1);
  
  // complete config
  console.log(config);
}

objasparam();
objasparam({
  obj1: { var1: 22, var2: "another string"}
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: I have now set in my function a defaults variable with all defaults and merged them

Answer (score 2):

There are two levels for defaults there:

1. Defaulting the properties of the object when destructuring it,
2. Providing a default for the object as a whole.

The first is via destructuring defaults, the second is via parameter defaults. An example is probably the best way to show this. I'll do one with just one parameter to keep it simple, but you can do it with multiple parameters as well:

```js
function objasparam(
  // Parameter default ------------vvvv
  {prop1 = 0, prop2 = "something"} = {}
  // ----^^^--------^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- destructuring defaults
) {
  console.log(`prop1 = ${prop1}, prop2 = ${prop2}`);
}

console.log("Calling the function with no parameter at all:");
objasparam();

console.log("Calling it with {prop1: 42}:");
objasparam({prop1: 42});

console.log("Calling it with {prop2: 'answer'}:");
objasparam({prop2: 'answer'});

console.log("Calling it with {prop1: 42, prop2: 'answer'}:");
objasparam({prop1: 42, prop2: 'answer'});
```

```css
/* Make the console take up the whole result pane */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Of course, if you want to require an object gets passed in, leave of the parameter default.

```js
function objasparam(
  {prop1 = 0, prop2 = "something"}
  // ----^^^--------^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- destructuring defaults
) {
  console.log(`prop1 = ${prop1}, prop2 = ${prop2}`);
}

try {
  console.log("Calling the function with no parameter at all:");
  objasparam(); // Fails because an object is expected
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

console.log("Calling it with {prop1: 42}:");
objasparam({prop1: 42});

console.log("Calling it with {prop2: 'answer'}:");
objasparam({prop2: 'answer'});

console.log("Calling it with {prop1: 42, prop2: 'answer'}:");
objasparam({prop1: 42, prop2: 'answer'});
```

```css
/* Make the console take up the whole result pane */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or if you only want to provide defaults for the case where the object isn't given at all, and not if it is, leave off the destructuring defaults:

```js
function objasparam(
  // Parameter default ------------vvvv
  {prop1, prop2} = {prop1: 0, prop2: "something"}
) {
  console.log(`prop1 = ${prop1}, prop2 = ${prop2}`);
}

console.log("Calling the function with no parameter at all:");
objasparam();

console.log("Calling it with {prop1: 42}:");
objasparam({prop1: 42});

console.log("Calling it with {prop2: 'answer'}:");
objasparam({prop2: 'answer'});

console.log("Calling it with {prop1: 42, prop2: 'answer'}:");
objasparam({prop1: 42, prop2: 'answer'});
```

```css
/* Make the console take up the whole result pane */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Finally: This can be nested, since destructuring allows nesting. Re-reading your question, I'm wondering if that's what you were trying to do:

```js
function objasparam(
  {                                     //   vvvv--- default for if the object has no `obj1`
      obj1: {prop1 = 0, prop2 = "something"} = {},
      obj2: {prop3 = "three", prop4 = "four"} = {}
  {                                     //    ^^^^--- default for if the object has no `obj2`
  } = {} // <=== parameter default if nothing is passed
) {
  console.log(`prop1 = ${prop1}`);
  console.log(`prop2 = ${prop2}`);
  console.log(`prop3 = ${prop3}`);
  console.log(`prop4 = ${prop4}`);
}

console.log("Calling the function with no parameter at all:");
objasparam();

console.log("Calling it with {obj1: {prop1: 42}}:");
objasparam({obj1: {prop1: 42}});

console.log("Calling it with {obj2: {prop4: 'quattro'}}:");
objasparam({obj2: {prop4: 'quattro'}});

console.log("Calling it with {obj1: {prop1: 42}, obj2: {prop4: 'quattro'}}:");
objasparam({obj1: {prop1: 42}, obj2: {prop4: 'quattro'}});
```

```css
/* Make the console take up the whole result pane */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if prop1.var1 = 0 and I want to get this 0 as default param it doesn´t get the 0 but undefined and this the problem

Comment: @Play_it - I can't make out what you're trying to do in your code, but the above lays out the principles to apply. If you can clarify what you're trying to do, perhaps show us some sample calls to `objasparam`, I can help you figure it out, but it'll be some variation on the above.